# Добавление слов в URL

Tags: javascript, html, url

Мне надо, чтобы я писал `id` в `text-area`, этот `id` заносился в переменную или массив, а потом этот `id` добавлялся в адресную строку по заготовленной ссылке, типа: `dumbsite.com/:id/preview`.

Надо, чтобы вместо `:id` был тот `id`, который я сам написал.
Или же, чтобы когда я написал свой `id` я нажимал по кнопке и переходил на эту ссылку с моим `id`.

Я пытался искать из примера `route` и `path`. Но там что-то про Node.js, а мне до этого ещё очень далеко.

Comment: Вас обязательно "загнобят", если не будете правильно оформлять вопросы.

Comment: вам надо сделать `location.href = "http://example.com/" + input.value` при клике на кнопку.

Comment: @teran, экранировать кто будет?

Comment: @Qwertiy топикстартер, очевидно

Comment: @teran, очевидно, нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy мне почему-то кажется, что это какая то приблуда для собственных нужд, а не для общественности, так что экранирования там особо не нужно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener('input', e => {
  var a = document.querySelector('a')
  a.textContent = a.href = "//dumbsite.com/:id/preview".replace(":id", encodeURIComponent(e.target.value))
})
```

```css
input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: .25em;
}

a {
  word-break: break-all;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<input autofocus>
<a></a>
```

Для смены текущего адреса страницы без перехода на неё можно использовать

```
history.replaceState(null, "", url)
```